# How can you create a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a .SQL file which creates the tables and inserts data. I am supposed to have a db.inc file stored in my include folder - that's the actual database. How can I create the db.inc file?

Note, this is a homework assignment, my file does have a CREATE DATABASE statement, but when I am connecting to the database with mysqli, I need a db.inc file, what is that file exactly?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking...you create a database with something like `CREATE DATABASE db_name`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you need. You may be looking for the \. command in MySQL which will let you run your .SQL file and create your database. Alternatively, are you maybe looking for a file that you include in, say, a PHP script that contains all of your database connection info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the .SQL File and add the command.

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name
```

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html